# Bootstrap date picker range selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to modify the Bootstrap checkin/checkout date example but I can't make it work.

The code disables the dates before now and when the checkin date is selected the checkout date is open and by default has select the next date. This is working fine, but I want when the checkout date to be open and suggest the next day to disable all dates before that next date.

Is it possible?

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
    }
    checkin.hide();
    $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
}).data('datepicker');
var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    checkout.hide();
}).data('datepicker')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option